# Sum the difference between created_at and updated_at (Rails ActiveRecord - Looking for a better way)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

TL;DR:

So I figure I do:

```
@user.resources.each do |r|
  #Something like this...
  r.views.sum(:created_at, :group=>:resource_id) - r.views.sum(:updated_at, :group=>:resource_id)
end
```

Now, I know I can get it to work like this:

```
r = Resource.first
time_sum_difference = r.views.sum {|v| v.updated_at.to_i - v.created_at.to_i}
```

But I'd rather have ActiveRecord calculate it for me

EDIT: Crap, can't sum timestamps obviously, need to calc the difference in place

Is there a better way to do this? Am I on the right track? (I'll be experimenting and updating this post until I figure it out)

Details:

I have a View model that is a join table between Resources and Users.

It has the standard timestamps: created_at and updated_at

I want to obtain the sum of the time spent on a resource submitted by a user.

In my Resource model:

```
has_many :views, :class_name => 'UserResourceView'
```

Then for the View:

```
class UserResourceView < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :resource_id, :user_id
  belongs_to :resource
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :resources
  has_many :resource_views, :class_name => 'UserResourceView'
  has_many :viewed_resources, :through => :resource_views, :source => :resource
...
end
```

UPDATE:

```
u.resources.joins(:views).group('resources.id').select('sum(views.created_at) as s_ca, sum(views.updated_at) as s_ua, s_ca - s_ua as diff').first

  Resource Load (0.7ms)  SELECT sum(views.created_at) as s_ca, sum(views.updated_at) as s_ua, s_ca - s_ua as diff FROM "resources" INNER JOIN "user_resource_views" ON "user_resource_views"."resource_id" = "resources"."id" WHERE "resources"."user_id" = 1 GROUP BY resources.id LIMIT 1
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "views"

LINE 1: SELECT  sum(views.created_at) as s_ca, sum(views.updated_at)...
                    ^
: SELECT  sum(views.created_at) as s_ca, sum(views.updated_at) as s_ua, s_ca - s_ua as diff FROM "resources" INNER JOIN "user_resource_views" ON "user_resource_views"."resource_id" = "resources"."id" WHERE "resources"."user_id" = 1 GROUP BY resources.id LIMIT 1
```

UPDATE 2:

```
u.resources.joins(:user_resource_views).group('resources.id').select('sum(user_resource_views.created_at) as s_ca, sum(user_resource_views.updated_at) as s_ua, s_ca - s_ua as diff')
ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'user_resource_views' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?
```

UPDATE 3 (more information):

From my schema.rb file:

```
create_table "user_resource_views", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "resource_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
  end
```

Comment: What db are you using?

Comment: We are running postgres

Answer (score 0):

This should work and minimize queries

```
@user.resources.joins(:views)
.group('resources.id')
.select('sum(views.created_at) as s_ca, sum(views.updated_at) as s_ua, s_ca - s_ua as diff')
```

I'm not sure if you can do the minus on the query but still without that it's a better way to do it

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I get an error, which I show at the bottom of my updated post

Comment: Replace views with user_resource_views

Comment: Changed my error to something else (see Update 2). Still working on it, I appreciate the help!

Comment: I can get it to work like: r = Resource.first;   
time_sum_difference = r.views.sum {|v| v.updated_at.to_i - v.created_at.to_i} *shrug*